# How to insert a space inside NiceArray while maintain alignment of \Block with \SubMatrix

Tags: math-mode, matrices, nicematrix

I am trying to align multiple math equations with braces using `nicematrix`

[image]

The result above is as desired but I would like to

1. Add small space after the third row. However, this causes the contents of `\Block{3-1}{j = 1, \dots, g}` to become unaligned with the brace. The image blow shows how this happens when using `\addlinespace[11mm]`

[image]

2. Get an elegant way to add small space after the third column which shifts the braces and the fourth column by a specific length. This is achieved using `@{\quad\hspace{1.1mm}}` before the fourth column with `[xshift=1.1mm]`

[image]

My MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\newcolumntype{e}{@{{$\mspace{\thinmuskip}$}}c@{{$\mspace{\thinmuskip}$}}}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{NiceArray}{r e l l}
        \alpha_X \times \alpha_Y & = & \chi   & \Block{3-1}{X < Y}
        \\
        \alpha_X \times \alpha_Y & = & \xi    &
        \\
        \alpha_X \times \alpha_Y & = & \zeta  & 
        \\
        \Upsilon_{j}             & = & 0      & \Block{3-1}{j = 1, \dots, g}
        \\
        \Psi_{j}                 & = & \sqrt{\sinh E - \tan^2\tfrac{F}{2}} &
        \\
        \Gamma_{j}               & = & F      &
    \CodeAfter
    \SubMatrix{.}{1-1}{3-3}{\}}
    \SubMatrix{.}{4-1}{6-3}{\}}
    \end{NiceArray}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{NiceArray}{r e l @{\quad\hspace{1.1mm}}l}
        \alpha_X \times \alpha_Y & = & \chi   & \Block{3-1}{X < Y}
        \\
        \alpha_X \times \alpha_Y & = & \xi    &
        \\
        \alpha_X \times \alpha_Y & = & \zeta  & 
        \\
        \addlinespace[11mm]
        \Upsilon_{j}             & = & 0      & \Block{3-1}{j = 1, \dots, g}
        \\
        \Psi_{j}                 & = & \sqrt{\sinh E - \tan^2\tfrac{F}{2}} &
        \\
        \Gamma_{j}               & = & F      &
        \CodeAfter
        \SubMatrix{.}{1-1}{3-3}{\}}[xshift=1.1mm]
        \SubMatrix{.}{4-1}{6-3}{\}}[xshift=1.1mm]
    \end{NiceArray}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please supply an MWE (from \documentclass... to \end{document}) that we can compile,

Comment: Are you running this more than once?  Is the posted code supposed to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1):

For the vertical space, I added a fictitious row and the added `\\[1cm]` (of course you can set the space you prefer).

For the horizontal space, I created a new column type `\newcolumntype{L}{l<{$\;$}}` (I used `\;` because it looks like the space in your example image; of course, you can change it into `$\quad$` or `\hspace{1.1mm}` or what you prefer).

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\newcolumntype{e}{@{{$\mspace{\thinmuskip}$}}c@{{$\mspace{\thinmuskip}$}}}
\newcolumntype{L}{l<{$\;$}}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{NiceArray}{r e L l}
        \alpha_X \times \alpha_Y & = & \chi   & \Block{3-1}{X < Y}
        \\
        \alpha_X \times \alpha_Y & = & \xi    &
        \\
        \alpha_X \times \alpha_Y & = & \zeta  & 
        \\
        \\[1cm]
        \Upsilon_{j}             & = & 0      & \Block{3-1}{j = 1, \dots, g}
        \\
        \Psi_{j}                 & = & \sqrt{\sinh E - \tan^2\tfrac{F}{2}} &
        \\
        \Gamma_{j}               & = & F      &
    \CodeAfter
    \SubMatrix{.}{1-1}{3-3}{\}}
    \SubMatrix{.}{5-1}{7-3}{\}}
    \end{NiceArray}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]